# Detecting Service Fabric upgrade is completed using .NET client

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Upgrading an existing SF application using .NET client with [`FabricClient.ApplicationManagementClient.UpgradeApplicationAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/system.fabric.fabricclient.applicationmanagementclient.upgradeapplicationasync.aspx) and getting the status of upgrade using [`FabricClient.ApplicationManagementClient.GetApplicationUpgradeProgressAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/system.fabric.fabricclient.applicationmanagementclient.getapplicationupgradeprogressasync.aspx). Last command returns [`ApplicationUpgradeProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/mt161339.aspx) with a property [`UpgradeStatus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/system.fabric.applicationupgradeprogress.upgradestate.aspx). I was hoping this enum ([`ApplicationUpgradeState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/system.fabric.applicationupgradestate.aspx)) based property would have a value of Completed or something similar, but there's nothing like that.

What is the right way to determine (using .NET client) that a given SF application has successfully completed? Is there a callback option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ApplicationUpgradeState.RollingForwardCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/system.fabric.applicationupgradestate.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @vaclav-turecek. For whatever the reason I was looking for just `Completed`.

Comment: Well, note that there is also a RollbackCompleted state too, because your upgrade may complete either by rolling forward or rolling back. So watch for both.

Comment: Absolutely. It's the RollingForwardCompleted that I've missed. Need new glasses prescription :)

Comment: ApplicationUpgradeState.Invalid - I'm not sure what's this one. Is that sort of "null" value?